# How to organize a million people to write a document?

Tags: open-source, document-management

I need to organize a group effort to write a document, the amount of people involved will be in the order of 10⁵ to 10⁶. Maybe actively working on the document 10³ and the rest working on a passive mode (i.e., proof reading, commenting ...)

Our group is very heterogeneous, thus making it challenging - some are familiar with programing but others not. I was thinking of using a version control (e.g., Git or similar) on a server, however it can be complicated for people that are not familiar with programming (in my opinion).

Is there any website or software that is user friendly that we can use to help on this task?

Thanks in advance, I.

Comment: When I started reading, I wanted to suggest Git to you right away ;P
One more idea would be a wiki software. But I think Git is easier with a Git GUI client.

Comment: adding to that, if it's THAT many people, it makes sense to seperate the document into multiple ones (one per chapter or whatever), to reduce the amount of people working on the same document at a time.

Comment: How does Wikipedia do it?

Comment: How big would the document be and how many changes per day do you expect? I see some challenges beside the sheer number of participants: mostly, how to make sure that the document still makes sense with people potentially changing it at hundreds of places at once

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica WP (or MediaWiki, the software driving it, to be precise) doesn't use a CVS for its articles. If you edit the same section or the whole article as someone else and the section/article is saved before you do so, you get an [edit conflict which can only be resolved manually](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Edit_conflict#Resolving_an_edit_conflict): 1) keep the other changes, abandon yours, re-apply yours or 2) keep your changes, abandon the others, re-apply the others, 3) & 4) do 1) or 2) and clarify with the other editor how a combined version should look in the end.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **GitHub website** for that, you can manage project or document by using that.

On the other hand you can use ***Google drive*** for that if you are only managing a document... so the newbies could also easily use it

Answer (score 0):

[SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/p/add_project) offers [Subversion](https://subversion.apache.org/) repositories which is a [CVS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrent_Versions_System) that's easier to handle than [Git](https://git-scm.com/) for non-programmers.

Anyway, for both Git and Subversion there's [TortoiseGit](https://tortoisegit.org/) and [TortoiseSVN](https://tortoisesvn.net/) which makes repos/workspaces, once set up, easy to handle with their Windows Explorer context menu integration.